# What happens to the variable in this case when it is overwritten with self?

Tags: python

I am downloading URLs in Python and need to detect 404s, so after some search I came up with:

```
import urllib
class MyUrlOpener(urllib.FancyURLopener):
    def retrieve(self, url, filename=None, reporthook=None, data=None):
        self.file_was_found = True
        val = urllib.FancyURLopener.retrieve(self, url, filename, reporthook, data)        
        return val

    def http_error_404(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data):
        url.file_was_found = False


def download_file(url, saveas):
    urlaccess = MyUrlOpener()
    localFile, headers = urlaccess.retrieve(url, saveas)
    return urlaccess.file_was_found
```

My question is that if you look at the source code (Python 2.7) for FancyURLopener then you see:

```
def http_error(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data=None):
    """Handle http errors.
    Derived class can override this, or provide specific handlers
    named http_error_DDD where DDD is the 3-digit error code."""
    # First check if there's a specific handler for this error
    name = 'http_error_%d' % errcode
    if hasattr(self, name):
        method = getattr(self, name)
        if data is None:
            result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
        else:
            result = method(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data)
        if result: return result
    return self.http_error_default(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
```

Which is passing the `url` as the first parameter and not `self`.  I thought that the first parameter to a function was always a reference to the class instance (by convention) and my code confirms this.  So what happens to the `url` value?

**UPDATE:** It turns out that `data==None` so it was calling the first signature. This foiled my attempts to manually add the self parameter.  As soon as I added the `=None` default to `data` in my `http_error_404` signature all was well (because it used the default).

The *fixed* / *correct* signature is `def http_error_404(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data=None):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, any class instance's method has [`self`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks) passed in by the Python interpreter and all of the other arguments are shifted down one place automatically.

In other words the Python interpreter rewrites:

```
urlaccess.retrieve(url, saveas)
```

into something that looks like this:

```
urlaccess.retrieve(urlaccess, url, saveas)
```

So you don't have to do it yourself.  However, since

> explicit is better than implicit

any instance methods you declare for a Python object must specify **explicitly** that they take the instance of the object as their first argument *even though Python will pass that argument without any action on the part of the programmer.*

The first argument does not *have* to be called `self` ... that is only a convention.

---

So, to actually answer your question though (as mluebke did) -- you need to specify the `self` argument.

```
def http_error_404(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data):
    url.file_was_found = False
    # Python is treating `url` as `self`
    # Therefore the URL is being saved in `fp`, `fp` in `errcode`, etc.
```

To fix this problem add a first argument to pick up the instance.

```
def http_error_404(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data):
    self.file_was_found = False
    # Now everything should work
```

Answer (score 3):

self is explicitly listed in the method definition, but implicitly passed when the method is called. Change your function to look like this and all your variables will start to line up again.

```
def http_error_404(self, url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers, data):
    self.file_was_found = False
```